# open activity from sub project in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a project library that have some logic that needs to open activity from application that based on this library

I can not add application as dependency, so How can I be able to open activity, please anyone advice

BaseApplication.java

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {

@Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        BaseApplication.mInstance = this;

        // Register global exception handler.
        UncoughtException crashHandler = UncoughtException.getInstance();
        crashHandler.init(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

UncoughtException.java

```
public class UncoughtException implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

@Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

        intent = new Intent(mContext, UncoughtExceptionActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

UncoughtExceptionActivity.java

```
public class UncoughtExceptionActivity extends Activity {

mReopenButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

ntent intent = new Intent(UncoughtExceptionActivity.this , SplashActivity.class);
UncoughtExceptionActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

SplashActivity is not found in the base module, it is found in another module and I want to open it from my current module

Comment: you are trying to start an activity from your application inside a included lib? Sounds for me, that the design of the lib is incorrect. please post your code that you have so fare, and specify which activity is in which project.

Comment: It is not a library, I am trying to restructure my app, and I have an activity that open if any crash happen that have re-open button, this activity is registered in the base application class, please check code attached in the question.

Comment: Are you importing `SplashActivity`? That should solve it.

Comment: @anthony I can not import it until I add dependance to the sub project and I can not add dependance to sub project as it will be cycle dependancies

Comment: how about giving the Activity classname  which you want to reopen, as parameter in your intent when you start the UncoughtExceptionActivity